2nd monitor on mini displayport only showing up with hot plug
I have Kubuntu 22.04. The laptop (lenovo thinkpad x230) has a mini displayport to connect a 2nd monitor, in my case actually a TV, I use a mini displayport to hdmi adapter.
The only way to get a picture on the tv monitor is to wait until Kubuntu is ready with booting and logging me in and then plug in the already running tv-monitor. Works like a charm, resolution and so, all perfect, system info shows the correct specs.
If I start Kubuntu with the cable plugged and the monitor on, nothing happens, no picture, no monitor in the system info, no monitor in xrandr output. If I start Kubuntu with the monitor plugged and off and then I turn the monitor on, the same, no picture. If I start Kubuntu with the monitor unplugged and then plug it in and then turn on the monitor, no picture. Even, if I plug the running monitor out in this situation and then in again, nothing happens.
This is pretty weird behaviour, isn´t it? Has anybody an idea, how I could fix this?
